# Cann't uninstall cordova completely

Tags: cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I have install cordova 9.0.0 then I want to back to cordova version 8.1.2

I have run this command `sudo npm uninstall -g cordova` then  `sudo npm install cordova@8.1.2`

But when I run cordova -v, cordova 9.0.0 display, although I run `ionic info` the output is cordova 8.1.2.

Please help.